# how to push a new view through navigationbutton class?

Tags: iphone

I have a class called `Button class`, which inherits from `UINavigationController`.In this class i have defined 4 buttons on navigation and these buttons are `Login Button`, Share Button, Like Button, Option Button..in the project there are many views and i want these buttons on every view.

so what i did is make an object of this class in every other class and call its `viewDidLoad` function in every class. The problem is here when i click on the Login button and try to push a 'sign in view' that's not actually happening.

Can any one help in this regard?

Comment: by calling viewDidLoad of button class in every class you refreshing viewDidLOad of buttonClass

Comment: you can create UIView class and add your buttons to it, then add this view on top of every viewcontroller and perform subsequent action using custom delegates